# Tabs issue when using php self

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

i have problem with jquery ui tabs.
When I pass my form data within tab 2 or any tab k to $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]  i got redirected to tab 1.

I tried:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {     
.
.
echo '<script>$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );</script>';
.
.
}
```

but it doesnt work.

I tried some other solutions but they dont work either.

I bet it is some trivial thing but cant figure it out.

I would appreciate if someone could help.

Cheers,
S

Comment: where are you putting this? how are you calling it. show full code;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The example you have provided does not include enough details to understand the issue. Please describe the steps or actions that are not working. Is this POST being done in AJAX? Is all of the jQuery UI loading? Any alerts in your browsers Console?